# Updating field with variable

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am coding with firebase. My problem is that the field is every time called at another number. So in a firestore document I have 6: value, or 23: value, ...
I am trying to get these fields like this:

```
 const data = doc.data();
 var number = 7;
 var el_already = data.[number];
        ...
```

But it already says, that the data.[el] is an unexpected token. The code brokes. I hope you can help me.
~filip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is syntactically incorrect. Correct code:

```
 ...
 var number = 7;
 var el_already = data[number]; // Remove "." after  "= data"
 ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Inside javascript objects numbers can not appear as keys. So you need to convert it to string when saving data and when retrieving data.

```
let obj = {};
let num = 23;
obj[num.toString()] = "Twenty three";

var usersRef = ref.child("users");
usersRef.set(obj);

const data = doc.data();
var number = 23;
var el_already = data.[number.toString()];
```

Comment: `Inside javascript objects numbers can not appear as keys.` that's not correct.

Comment: Any value used as a property name is automatically converted to a string.